# Do different blockchains have caps on different amounts of possible emitted events?

Tags: events

For example, a transaction that emits 1,000 events, would that work on Arbitrum, Optimism, Ethereum, etc? All EVM compatible chains/

Answer (score 0):

Different blockchains have different limits on the number of events that can be emitted by a smart contract to stop the spamming on the network

Ethereum allows around 32 Events per transaction